# Explain what this Prolog program does?

Tags: prolog

I am working on Prolog and I came across the below program. When I execute this program with a query for example:  `mysterious([2,3,4,5,6,7,8],L)`, it gives me the answer 20. I don't understand the flow of getting this result. Can anyone help me to understand this code?

How does it produce the answer 20 for the above mentioned query?

```
mysterious([],0).
mysterious([X],X).
mysterious([X,Y|Xs], Res) :-
    mysterious(Xs, Res1),
    Res is X + Res1.
```

Comment: Why don't you try to trace the execution? Call `?- trace.` and then run the query again, stepping through it.

Comment: Also, try asking `mysterious([],L)`, `mysterious([8],L)`, `mysterious([7,8],L)`, `mysterious([6,7,8],L)` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is such a basic program, I will give you a hint. First off, this:

```
foo([]).
foo([X]).
foo([X,Y|Rest]) :-
    foo(Rest).
```

could be also written as:

```
foo([]).
foo([First|Rest]) :-
    bar(Rest, First).

bar([], Last).
bar([This|Rest], Prev) :-
    foo(Rest).
```

It is unnecessarily verbose, but more explicit. In your case, however, it makes something obvious:

```
mysterious([], 0).
mysterious([X|Rest], Result) :-
    myst_1(Rest, X, Result).

myst_1([], Result, Result).
myst_1([_Y|Rest], X, Result) :-
    mysterious(Rest, Result1),
    Result is X + Result1.
```

Something which you did not mention in your question is that the compiler must have given you a "singleton variable" warning on the *Y* in the last clause of `mysterious/2`. This should have been a strong indication of what is going on already.

Comment: @WillNess The original predicate in the question is also not deterministic on the most common Prolog implementations. P.S. I finally understood what you mean about first and second snippet not being the same. Thank you!

Comment: @WillNess Note to self: first think, then talk (to yourself), then write. I will leave the corrected answer but I don't think it is useful at all. Your comments however were useful, at least to me.

Answer (score 2):

I can help you by commenting lines, maybe you will understand the prolog a little more, let's start:

> Prolog programs describe relations, defined by means of clauses. Pure Prolog is restricted to Horn clauses. There are two types of clauses: facts and rules. (by wikipedia)

```prolog
% comment in prolog starts with '%'
mysterious([],0).  % its called 'predicate', something like functions in imperative
                   % languages. it has two arguments: [], and 0. and it is ended
                   % by dot (.). Clauses with empty bodies are called facts. 
                   % (this is fact).

mysterious([X],X). % is actually a "rule" that says, "if the list has one element, 
                   % then the result is just that element". (by @mbratch)

mysterious([X,Y|Xs], Res) :- % now, when argument 1 is list which looks like
                             % [SomeElement, NextElement|LastElements],
  mysterious(Xs, Res1),      % call 'mysterious' with only LastElements 
                             % and variable Res1 (skip first two elements of list)
  Res is X + Res1.           % then add first element to Res1.

% it calculates the sum of every second element of list, beginning on first.
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Dew for you explanation. appreciated!!

Comment: if the question is already answered you can accept it ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: One could argue that the second clause `mysterious([X], X).` is actually a "rule" (rather than a "fact") that says, "if the list has one element, then the result is just that element", or short for `mysterious([X], R) :- X = R.`